# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse blocks 30-60 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

currently in one of our apps I see big lags when executing the first HTTP Webrequest. According to our logs there is a lag of 30 - 60 seconds. It blocks at HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse

Here is a quote from the MSDN:

> The BeginGetRequestStream method requires some synchronous setup tasks
>   to complete (DNS resolution, proxy detection, and TCP socket
>   connection, for example) before this method becomes asynchronous. As a
>   result, this method should never be called on a user interface (UI)
>   thread because it might take some time, typically several seconds. In
>   some environments where the webproxy scripts are not configured
>   properly, this can take 60 seconds or more. The default value for the
>   downloadTime attribute on the  config file element is
>   one minute which accounts for most of the potential time delay.

I understand that there is DNS resolution, proxy detection and other stuff required. But 30-60 seconds is way too long. When I enter the same URL in any browser I get the page immediately. When I resolve DNS manual there is also no delay.
All concurrent requests to the same URI don't block. When I restart the application the first request blocks again for min. 30 seconds.

Is this a known problem? Is there a bug? We see this on different machines, So I don't think my developer machine is the problem.

Here is some example code:

```
private void TestWebRequest()
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://matrix.ag-software.de/http-bind");
   request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
   request.Method = "POST";   
   request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);            
}

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
   //
}
```

**update:** This must be a problem with my Windows 7 Installation. I have tested 2 other machines and can't cause the same problem there. I have seen logfiles from customers with exactly the same problems. This seems to happen under some conditions on some machines.

Comment: Is this targeting intranet or internet url?

Comment: I added some example code. I have the problem with internal and external. Maybe its only a problem against this specific server implementation and could be solved with some special settings.

On MONO we don't have this problem. Currently I am debugging on the full .NET framework 3.5. The problem does not exists on all framework version. Silverlight for example seems to work fine, but it uses the browser stack.

Comment: Have you tried if against any other sites like google or stackoverflow?  Does it exist then?

Comment: yes, when I replace the URI in the example I posted with http://www.google.com it blocks as well for a while.

Comment: If you resolve the name and use the IP address in the BeginGetResponse method, does that solve the problem?

Comment: no, same problem when I use IP addresses instead of domains names. I tried to debug the .NET Framework codes, but for some reason VS2012 does not load the symbols :(

Comment: I can't say I believe it is a known issue as I don't experience the same issues as you do, but have you thought about an async call to "prime" the connection during the start up of the application?  While I agree it isn't ideal, you could at least have a work around while we try to find an actual solution

Comment: The app is already completely async. At startup we need to process the response of the first webrequest which causes a big delay.

Answer (score 1):

I have just happened through the same.

I found out that the Microsoft Client Firewall was generating it. I was using it to avoid navigate through my company's proxy. My first workaround was to set the `request.Proxy` hard-coded. To avoid that ugly line of code I end up disabling the Microsoft Client Firewall and setting the proxy on Internet Options.

Hope this helps.

As @EricLaw said, System.Net logging may help. Here is a link to MSDN to [Enable System.Net logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203855.aspx).

Comment: Slow detection of proxies is often a cause of delayed requests. Enabling System.NET logging will help reveal whether that's the cause of a particular .NET WebRequest performance problem.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw. I'll give it a look because I had only a few URIs taking that long.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. There's more information available in these links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/939e78bf-b9be-4d0b-894e-ae7f0d6013ff

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2cb74a7e-6e8f-4d05-b86a-2401df5d2ed3/

Comment: yes I have seen these threads before. But not sure if this is exactly the same problem. I don't get the exceptions listed in this threads. And these threads are pretty old, if this is an .NET issue it should be fixed already in latest versions like 3.5, 4 and 4.5.

Comment: @Pete: You should give a summary of what the conclusion is in the links as link-only answers are not allowed.